# hMailServer - server scripts - trigger external DLL function?

Tags: c#, signalr, hmail-server, email-processing

maybe it is a dummy question and there exists better approaches, but I wonder if there is any possibility of catching an event on incoming email using server side script and inside that script would be external DLL call or script which connect to database and writes some metadata from incoming message (same as external DLL would)?

The scenario could be:

1. Message is coming to hMailServer from sender
2. Some trigger starts
3. Trigger calls function in external DLL which would parse the email body a writes data about recipient, subject, message perex and
   attachment count to special database table for speedlisting and
   email notification purposes which could be located in the same
   database as hmailserver
4. let the message to be delivered

Goal: to have instant information about all emails containing from, to, subject, message perex(first 100 chars), attachments flag and read flag accessible through SQL query without having to connect to IMAP or PO3. So using one SQL query I can get all notifications for all accounts and send them through signalR.

I realised that in MS SQL database of hmailserver is table called hm_messages which is automatically filled when email arrives but contains no subject, mostly no sender and definitely no body and attachment count. Row in that table contains only information about account, folder, flags, dates and name of *.eml file. I could write a trigger with SQLCLR function which could do the same as mentioned above but even if I have *.eml file name I do not have its actual location on the hard drive. So I am back to square one.

Otherwise I have to download messages from all accounts in a time loop, which is stealing my server CPU and memory especially where there is about 60 email accounts and thousands of messages in them and have to iterate them all over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hMailServer` supports scripting in VBScript/JScript and supplies [events](https://www.hmailserver.com/documentation/latest/?page=scripting_onacceptmessage) to indicate new message arrival.

Both scripting languages support COM so can use for example ADO to connect to a database or can interoperate with a (late bound) COM Visible .Net assembly.

So yes, it can do what you ask but I would think carefully about the scalability of doing this

Comment: I know about this possibility but could you be more specific how I can use late bound assembly in that script and provide brief script example? And what did you mean by scalability of doing that?

Comment: For a simple insertion you can use the capability of VBScript or JScript without bothering with .Net.  If you want to bother you need to research creating a COM visible assembly and how to then use the COM object in VBScript (`CreateObject`) or JScript (`new ActiveXObject`)

Comment: I would suggest looking for a product that unlike hMailServer (afaik) maintains its own database that contains the complete message.

Comment: I do not know about any enough mature email client with C# api support like hMailServer so I gues I will have to try. And also have basic functionality already implemented but without signalR notifications. I will definitely try VBScript even though I have no experience with that and there is probably no way of debugging the script.

Answer (score 0):

As you found out your self, you can use VB-Script and JScript to run hMailServer specific Events, invoked by C:\Program Files (x86)\hMailServer\Events\EventHandlers.vbs

You also can use any COM/DCOM Language or Toolkit which can access Microsoft COM
Technology. hMailServers Main Server Object is a OutOfProcess Server which supports
late binding and Typelib based late access.

To use it via Runtime binding you can just call any hMailServer COM API Object
with VB-Script. If you want to access hMailServer by C#.NET or VB.NET or native C/C++
you need to import hMailServers Typelibe (hMailServer.tlb it hMailServer \bin folder)

Examples how you can access hMailServer from C# and other Languages can be found
in the following Articles:

**C#.NET**
https://www.hmailserver.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=21&t=31507

**VB.NET**
https://www.hmailserver.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=21&t=31508

**Native C/C++ (Win32/Win64)**
https://www.hmailserver.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=21&t=31510

**COM-API Documentation**
https://www.hmailserver.com/documentation/latest/?page=com_objects

Required tools:
Visual Studio 2013 but not earlier and not above.